# Case with Select and Null Check

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
select a.AgentId,
       case(select acs.IsConnected
            from rmm.tblAgentConnectionStatus acs
            where acs.AgentName = a.AgentName)
        when 1 then 'True'
        when 0 then 'False'
        when null then 'False'
        end as ConnectionStatus
from Sentilan2.rmm.tblAgent a
order by AgentName asc
```

I have the above, but it results in ConnectionStatus being null when their is no corresponding row in `tblAgent`.

Is it possible for the result to be `False` when the column is null.

Current output

```
AgentId                                 ConnectionStatus
010D0206-5D8C-4AB1-90B6-7BD0C2773E22    True
CA4C48DD-3D2E-4948-9F93-254CDF081658    True
1DB90EE5-D96A-4071-8F51-26B3130EC6D4    NULL
ACA694D0-0C1D-45BA-80DD-273F41BD70B1    NULL
941B539B-7CA0-4472-ABCD-2777AE8B2E5D    NULL
1E7DDA4D-C119-4E47-8478-277952024FD1    NULL
```

I'd like those nulls to be false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `coalesce()` or `isnull()` to substitute a value for `null`:

```
select a.AgentId,
       case coalesce((select acs.IsConnected
            from rmm.tblAgentConnectionStatus acs
            where acs.AgentName = a.AgentName),0)
        when 1 then 'True'
        when 0 then 'False'
        end as ConnectionStatus
from Sentilan2.rmm.tblAgent a
order by AgentName asc
```

Or just `else 'False'`:

```
select a.AgentId,
       case (select acs.IsConnected
            from rmm.tblAgentConnectionStatus acs
            where acs.AgentName = a.AgentName)
        when 1 then 'True'
        else 'False'
        end as ConnectionStatus
from Sentilan2.rmm.tblAgent a
order by AgentName asc
```

Comment: Great, thanks!  I didn't know you could do `else` in a `case`.... P.S, invader Zim is great!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a LEFT OUTER JOIN with a COALESCE between the two tables.

That way, you'll get what you need from tblAgent, but False where IsConnected is NULL or no corresponding row in tblAgentConnectionStatus exists

```
select 
   a.AgentId,
   case(coalesce(acs.IsConnected, 0))
      when 1 then 'True'
      else 'False'
    end as ConnectionStatus
from Sentilan2.rmm.tblAgent a
left join Sentilan2.rmm.tblAgentConnectionStatus acs
  on acs.AgentName = a.AgentName
order by a.AgentName asc
```

One thing that I would recommend is NOT joining on AgentName.  That compares strings.

It would be more efficient to establish a integer foreign key between the two tables (where it is the primary key in the referenced table).  This will make the query faster, especially if you index the foreign key.

I have demonstrated this within [this SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b78a9/2)

Comment: Using `case ,,, when null then ...` won't work since NULLs don't play nicely in tests for equality. Try `declare @Foo as Int = NULL; select case @Foo when NULL then 'null' else 'oops' end;` to see it fail. To test for NULL you need to use `is NULL`.

Comment: Whoops!  Update my solution to reflect this.  I used COALESCE

Answer (score 0):

The correct test for a null value is `is NULL`. Unfortunately, that requires repeating the value for each `when` clause within the `case` expression. There are various ways to avoid repeating the correlated subquery, e.g. a common table expression (CTE). In this case a `left outer join` will suffice.

```
select a.AgentId,
       case
         when acs.IsConnected = 1 then 'True'
         when acs.IsConnected = 0 then 'False'
         when acs.IsConnected is null then 'False'
         else 'Oops: ' + Cast( acs.IsConnected as VarChar(64) )
         end as ConnectionStatus
  from Sentilan2.rmm.tblAgent as a left outer join
    rmm.tblAgentConnectionStatus as acs on acs.AgentName = a.AgentName
  order by AgentName asc;
```

Tip: It is generally a good idea to include an `else` clause in `case` expressions to catch any unexpected values.

Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.